# SQL query to check for date but ignore blank fields

Tags: asp.net, sql, select, getdate

I have an .asp script that runs the following SQL statement;

```
set rstmp = CustomQuery("select * from SysRes_Master where DATEDIFF(day, GETDATE(), DateChkIn)<1")
```

What this returns on the webpage is any record with a date in the "DateChkIn" field that is older then the days date (current). However, if this field is blank that record is also returned.

How can I modify this so that is still returns the expired record but ignores any records with a blank in the same?

Comment: Add to the end of query `AND DateChkIn is not null`

Answer (score 0):

I would really consider choosing the fields you want in your select,
getting more data than necessary is the first thing to performance tune,

if i understand your question right your problem is that you get the DateChkln field too,
so selecting the field you want should filter off other fields

if you got multiple fields with dates, you can use the coalesce
that checks for nulls (google it)

what database do you have? mysql?, windows?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the properties of DateChkIn,

```
set rstmp = CustomQuery("select * from SysRes_Master where DATEDIFF(day, GETDATE(), DateChkIn) < 1 AND DateChkIn > 0")
```

or

```
set rstmp = CustomQuery("select * from SysRes_Master where DATEDIFF(day, GETDATE(), DateChkIn) < 1 AND DateChkIn IS NOT NULL")
```